# Get response from a specific question if form has optional questions field

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I understand we can get the value of a specific question from `.getItemResponses()` using the question index.

What happens if my Google Form has optional questions and/or questions which may skip certain sections? With those scenarios, the number of `itemresponses` changes.

How do I workaround this?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please show what you have tried..

Comment: Hi @Rubén, I'm actually clueless regarding this.
I've tried form.getResponses()[length-1].getItemResponses()[length-1].getResponse(); 
as the uploading is the last question. It worked for a day and suddenly had this error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getResponse')
myFunction @ Code.gs:6
Even if that had worked, it will not be particularly useful as I'm getting values out of other questions as well

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no direct way of getting a specific answer from a `FormResponse` object. I like to use a little helper function that iterates over the `ItemResponse[]` of the `FormResponse` and creates an object for all the answers:

```
/**
 * gets a key/value pair of answers for the given formresponse
 * the key will be the question and the value is the answer
 * @param {FormResponse} formResponse
 * @returns {Object}
 */    
function getAnswersFromFormResponse(formResponse) {
  const answers = {};
  const itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();
  for(const index in itemResponses) {
    const itemResponse = itemResponses[index];
    const question = itemResponse.getItem().getTitle();
    const answer = itemResponse.getResponse();
    answers[question] = answer;
  }
    
  return answers;
}
```

Concerning your comment: It looks like the same length was used for the `formResponse` and the `itemResponses`, or is this just pseudo-code?